# Get minimum price from last 30 days and the last price before that, quickly

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, timescaledb, postgresql-performance

I have below price audit table in timescale db. When I get new price I should calculate minimum price in last 30 days. But our price data not daily. In every price changes I write date and price to table. Problem is when I try to find the minimum price, I have to go before the last 30 days because there is not enough data. Also there are 130 Million rows in the table.

[image: Example Range]

In this case minimum price should be 120. Because this product sold for 120 ₺ between 12 July to 4 August.

DDL Example:

```
create table price_audit (
    timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
    partnerid varchar(200)             not null,
    productid varchar(200)             not null,
    price     numeric(12, 2)
);

alter table price_audit
    owner to appuser;

create index _price_audit_timestamp_idx
    on price_audit (timestamp desc);

create index productid_time_desc
    on price_audit (productid asc, timestamp desc)
    where (productid IS NOT NULL);

create index partnerid_time_desc
    on price_audit (partnerid asc, timestamp desc)
    where (partnerid IS NOT NULL);

create index partnerid_productid_time_desc
    on price_audit (partnerid asc, productid asc, timestamp desc)
    where ((partnerid IS NOT NULL) AND (productid IS NOT NULL));
```

Data Example:

[image: Example Data]

Insert Query :

```
insert into price_audit ("timestamp", partnerid, productid, price)
values ('2022-07-09 18:18:39.000000 +00:00','b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53','ABCTEST1', 120.00),
       ('2022-08-05 21:19:40.000000 +00:00','b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53','ABCTEST1',130.00),
       ('2022-08-10 11:20:39.000000 +00:00','b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53','ABCTEST1',140.00);
```

When new price came, we should not include in range:
New Price Date: 2022/08/11
30 days subtracted date: 2022/07/12

The following queries **take the first price older than 30 days, along with prices from the last 30 days, and return the minimum.**

```
SELECT min(price) from price_audit
         where (timestamp >= (select timestamp from price_audit
         where timestamp < '2022-07-12T15:30:00-00:00' and productid = 'ABCTEST1' and partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53'
         order by timestamp desc limit 1) or
         timestamp >= '2022-07-12T15:30:00-00:00' and timestamp < '2022-08-11T15:30:00-00:00') and 
         productid = 'ABCTEST1' and partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53' and price > 0
```

The other one with MAX:

```
SELECT min(price) from price_audit
         where (timestamp >= (select MAX(timestamp) from price_audit
         where timestamp < '2022-07-12T15:30:00-00:00' and productid = 'ABCTEST1' and partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53') or
         timestamp >= '2022-07-12T15:30:00-00:00' and timestamp < '2022-08-11T15:30:00-00:00') and
         productid = 'ABCTEST1' and partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53' and price > 0
```

Query Cost : 76

Actually this queries working well but I am not sure that all cases is ok. Because if there any data in 2022/07/12:00:00:00 query working wrong. But it's okay, I can ignore that.

Also, approximate run time is 50-100ms. If that query is ok I want to reduce it below 50Ms because I may have to run this query 1M times in 1 day.

How can we improve the performance of this query?

Comment: No `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS)`, not much chance of an answer.

Comment: You might find this a useful resource to help format the EXPLAIN output https://explain.depesz.com/ and also it could be worth checking through this info about query best practice https://www.timescale.com/forum/t/sql-query-filtering-best-practices/113

Comment: Please remember to provide data as text, never as image. We cannot copy/paste from an image, among other downsides.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you are including the time? That would mean you don't want the minimum of the previous 30 days, but the minimum of the previous 2592000 seconds? In any case, you should include that point in time when looking for the price valid at the start of this period. This is, if there is a price change on that day or second this would be your price, not a price before that moment.

Comment: These rows are written when the price changes. On the dates between the two lines, the product is sold at the first line price. When we need the last 30 days minimum price, we don't know when the price changed before the last 30 days. That's why we got the first row before the last 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> take the first price older than 30 days, along with prices from the last 30 days, and return the minimum

I expect this to perform better:

```sql
SELECT LEAST (
  (SELECT min(price)
   FROM   price_audit
   WHERE  partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53'
   AND    productid = 'ABCTEST1'
   AND    price > 0
   AND    timestamp >= '2022-07-12 15:30:00-00:00'
  )
, (SELECT price
   FROM   price_audit
   WHERE  partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53'
   AND    productid = 'ABCTEST1'
   AND    price > 0
   AND    timestamp < '2022-07-12 15:30:00-00:00'
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC
   LIMIT  1
   )
   );
```

Your index `partnerid_productid_time_desc` should be good for this, but this index should be much better:

```
CREATE INDEX price_audit_partnerid_productid_time_desc ON price_audit (partnerid, productid, timestamp DESC) INCLUDE (price)  -- ① 
WHERE  price > 0;  -- ②
```

① The covering index only makes sense if you get index-only scans out of it. See:

- [Advantage of using INCLUDE as against adding the column in INDEX for covering index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/313280/3684)
- [Do covering indexes in PostgreSQL help JOIN columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190151/3684)

② Only makes sense if excluding a sizable percentage of rows.

`WHERE partnerid IS NOT NULL  AND productid IS NOT NULL` (like you have now) never makes sense since both columns are defined `NOT NULL`.

Aside:
I would not use the name "timestamp" for a `timestamptz` column. Best not to use basic type names as identifiers at all. Too confusing.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your detailed answer . Your query cost is 19 and runtime is 25-50Ms. Mine was 76. In any case your query seems more faster. After implementation, I will accept your answer.

Comment: If we want to know, what price was valid at '2022-07-12 15:30:00-00:00', we must include that moment for the case that the price changed exactly then. I.e. `AND timestamp <= '2022-07-12 15:30:00-00:00'` , not `<`, in the limit subquery.

Comment: The query fails, if there were no price changes in the last 30 days. In that case the first subquery returns null, and `LEAST` returns null then, too. But that should only be the case when there was no price entry at all in the table (i.e. the new price is the first price ever).

Comment: Even If first query result is null, LEAST return second query result. In our case there is no way 2 query results is null.

Comment: I am sorry for this misinformation. It is great that `LEAST` works thus in PostgreSQL. I didn't know that nulls get ignored. I know `LEAST` from Oracle and MySQL, and there any parameter being null makes the result null, which is a great nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if my query has a chance of being faster than yours. Just try.

Here is what I do: As there should be an index on (productid, partnerid), it should be very quick to find all prices of interest. The new price included, we look at all previous prices. Once we've done that we only look at those valid after the start of the 30 day period. So, the first previous price is the one that was valid in the very moment of the period's start. And the last price is the one that was valid, before we entered the new one.

```
select min(prev_price)
from
(
  select
    timestamp, 
    lag(price) over (order by timestamp) as prev_price,
    max(timestamp) over () as max_timestamp
  from price_audit
  where productid = 'ABCTEST1'
  and partnerid = 'b319406e-2ca7-4663-a203-68a1928fdc53'
  and price > 0
) t
where timestamp > max_timestamp - interval '30 days';
```

It would help with the sorting, if the index included the timestamp, too. And as the only column missing then would be the price, we can even add that, so we get a covering index. So we end up with the same index that Erwin Brandstetter proposes in his answer, except for the ordering of the timestamp, where I would prefer ascending order for my query (but I guess it doesn't really make a difference).

```
create index idx on price_audit(productid, partnerid, timestamp) include price where price > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't understand how can we get max(timestamp).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot the `OVER` clause.

Comment: I get it now. I think there is a problem. If there is no data last 2 month we still get the 120 ₺. But it should be 130.

Comment: I changed the months. 
 
2022-03-10 11:20:39.000000 ,140.00 ₺
2022-04-09 18:18:39.000000 ,120.00 ₺
2022-05-05 21:19:40.000000 ,130.00 ₺
Today                                          ,110.00 ₺ (not include to calculation)

MinPrice 130 ₺ because yesterday selling price was 130 ₺

Comment: I am getting 130. See demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/fkYElmRd

Comment: Yes you getting 130 because you added new price before calculation. I have one more question. We just have 3 or 4 rows right now. In live db can be 1K-2K price for one product. We don't have any range of date. it could be problem when data will be bigger.

Comment: Yep, I expect the new price to be in the table. This is what I meant with "The new price included, we look at all previous prices." Sorry that this was not clear. Some thousands of table rows shouldn't be a problem for the DBMS. And it will use the index, because this is a very small part of the whole table stil (2K / 130M = 0,0015%). I see no problem with this.

Comment: If you are really running into performance problems, you can have some batch job that inserts rows for all current prices on given days, say once a year or once half a year. Thus you know you will find a price in that range and don't have to look back to all rows for the product, but only at the rows within the last year (or half a year or whatever the period you decide for).

Comment: I should accept that this is different perspective . But this query is depend on  new price. I want to know minimum price for last 30 days but there is no price change. Query result should be 110 not 130 right. I changed years.
https://dbfiddle.uk/gER8H-y2

Comment: Yep, now you are looking at the new price of 2021-09-13 and the minimum price of the thirty previous days. I.e. this still works perfectly, even if your boss says: we have a new price since last week, what was the minimum price in the thirty days before? If you don't want to add the new price to the database (but why not?), add it to your query instead, i.e. union the new price row (demo https://dbfiddle.uk/BbO9BW3m).

Comment: You can even add the new price row to the table, make your thirty day evaluation, and if you don't like the result, rollback the transaction.

Comment: Thank you so much Thorsten for your answer and valuable comments. I will compare two queries